# Scrapy: Creating a Request to a site that is not in allowed_domains

Tags: python, scrapy

I am scraping a certain website. Under certain conditions, I might want to make a Request to go to a website that is not listed in allowed_domains. Is that possible? If not, can I temporarily add the domain in there, create a Request and then remove the domain from my parser callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `dont_filter=True` on a `Request` object ([documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request)):

> dont_filter (boolean) – indicates that this request should not be
>   filtered by the scheduler.

Example:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.http import Request


class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'wikipedia'
    allowed_domains = ['en.wikipedia.org']
    start_urls = [
        'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        print "I'm at wikipedia"
        request = Request(url="https://google.com", 
                          callback=self.parse_google, 
                          dont_filter=True)
        yield request

    def parse_google(self, response):
        print "I'm at google"
```